# Is there a way to create a chat box for which the user doesnt have to log in?

Tags: circuit-sdk

What im looking to do is setup a chatbox on my website that allows the user to start a conversation with an employee(who has an circuit account) without the user needing to log in or even having an account.

From looking at it it would probably be possible to set this up by sending all the messages through a webhook and a Bot-Account but that probably wouldn't be too clean. As far as I know Circuit allows external Users to just join a call without an account so i was hoping there may be some functionality for what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, at this time all users need to be logged in to access the Circuit APIs. There are plans to allow unauthenticated users to have limited access such as starting a call, or sending a message, but there is no set timeline for this.

A workaround would be to use a pool of users, and use their credentials on the public website. But note this is not very secure, nor a clean solution since all unauthenticated users (on the public website) would use the same user accounts and essentially could decode the credentials. But for a prototype this might be ok.

A pool app on the server side that has a few users credentials configured could serve an HTTP endpoint and provide the credentials to the public site. The public site would then use those credentials to create a new conversation and post the message.